# Custom Windows charging in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Flink's `TimeWindow` functionality to perform some computations. I am creating a 5 minute `Window`. However I want to create a one hour `Window` for only the first time. The next Windows I need are of 5 minutes.

Such that for the first hour, data is collected and my operation is performed on it. Once this is done, every five minutes the same operation is performed.

I figure out this can be implemented with a `trigger` but I am not sure which `trigger` I should use and how.

UPDATE: I don't think even `triggers` are helpful, from what I can get, they just define the time/count triggering per `window`, not when the first `window` is to be triggered.

Comment: I doubt that this is possible with the current DataStream API. If you define a window, the definition is "the same" for all instances that are build during runtime... The only way would be to define a custom operator and add it to your program via `.transform(...)` -- but this seems quite cumbersome to get done right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not trivial to implement.

Given a `KeyedStream` you have to use a `GlobalWindow` and a custom stateful `Trigger` which "remembers" whether is has fired for the first time or not.

```
val stream: DataStream[(String, Int)] = ???
val result = stream
  .keyBy(0)
  .window(GlobalWindows.create())
  .trigger(new YourTrigger())
  .apply(new YourWindowFunction())
```

Details about `GlobalWindow` and `Trigger` are in the Flink [Window documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/streaming/windows.html).